# Tablerates depends weight and price

Tags: magento-1.9, table-rates

I saw that tablerates can depend of the weight or the price.
But depend on the destination, the shipping price must not be calculated following the same parameter.
For example, for France, the shipping price is based on the total price of the cart and for others countries, is based on the weight.

Is it possible to establish a tablerate like that without using and extension ? If yes, how ?

I found this [extension](http://support.webshopapps.com/productmatrix/) but I prefered to not use it if it's possible.